How to call a callback prop when another prop changes without omitting useEffect dependencies?
I have a simple dialog component that takes an open prop to control whether the dialog is shown or not, and an onOpen prop which is a callback to be run every time the dialog opens.
I can achieve this very simply like this:
const MyDialog = ({ open, onOpen, children }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      onOpen()
    }
  }, [open])


  // The dialog that gets rendered uses a UI library’s dialog component.
  return (
    <UnderlyingDialogComponent open={open}>
      {children}
    </UnderlyingDialogComponent>
  )
}

This works perfectly fine, except for the fact that the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps linting rule (from eslint-plugin-react-hooks) tells me that I need to include onOpen in the dependency array for the useEffect.
If I do that however, then the onOpen callback also gets called whenever the onOpen callback changes, which is not the behaviour that I want. I want it only to be called when the open prop changes from false to true.
Is there a simple way to do this without just disabling the linting rule? Or is this a situation where I can ignore the “rule” that all dependencies must be included in the dependency array?
Edit: I am aware that if the onOpen handler is made using useCallback then it shouldn't change, but I can't guarantee that any user of this component will do that. I would like my component to function correctly regardless of whether the user has used useCallback for their onOpen handler.

onOpen is an external dependency and should be included in the useEffect hoo's dependency array. Where/how is the onOpen changing? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

@DrewReese This is a component that could be used by anyone, I can't enforce that they are using useCallback for their onOpen function. I would like my component to work correctly regardless of whether onOpen changes or not.

Users of your code should understand that using useMemo and useCallback is how you memoize and provide stable references as props to components in React. If they don't understand that then that's on them. Including onOpen in the dependency is how you correctly use the useEffect hook so when it does change from higher up your effect is calling the correct "version" of it. Imagine how confused/frustrated users would be if they are passing down updated instances of the callback yet your code invokes some stale instance.

@DrewReese And what if the value of the onOpen callback legitimately changed (e.g. due to a dependency change in useCallback)? In that case I still don't want to call onOpen because the dialog has not changed from closed to open.

Then something off the top of my head I'd suggest is tracking when the open prop changes from false to true, and vice-versa, e.g. implement a usePrevious hook recipe, such that you only invoke onOpen when open updates from false to true from any previous render.

Another alternative would be to just stash onOpen in a React ref and call that from the useEffect callback closure, eliminating it as an external dependency.

You can consider a custom hook, useEffectEvent to help you handle this. React is currently experimenting with a feature like this, so you can also import it with:
import { experimental_useEffectEvent as useEffectEvent } from 'react';

or, you can create something similar which you maintain yourself by using a polyfill such as this one.
This hook will return a stable function reference across all re-renders, so it doesn't need to be included in your dependency array. It also has the added advatnage of always calling the "latest" onOpen function, avoiding potential stale closure issues within that callback. You can use it like so in the MyDialog component:
const MyDialog = ({ open, onOpen, children }) => {
  const onOpenHandler = useEffectEvent(onOpen);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      onOpenHandler();
    }
  }, [open]);

  ...
}


Keep an eye out for the current limitations with the callback you get back from this hook. Also, it's worth considering if you need an effect here in the first place. For example, if your inner dialog has an onOpen event you can tap into, as using that would be better to call your onOpen callback.

useEffectEvent looks really interesting, thanks for this! I'll use it with caution as it's experimental, but this could be exactly what I need (for this scenario and others). Good call with the underlying dialog as well; I've been trying to avoid that to keep this component as implementation-independant as possible, but in this case it might be worth hooking into any handlers that they expose.

While adding the dependency is one of the right ways to do it, if you do not want it to only be triggered when open changes to true, you can do track the previous value to make the correct updates:
Keep a ref to
 const ref = useRef();

 /** your other effect **/
useEffect(() => {
    if (open && !ref.current) {
      onOpen()
    }
  }, [open,onOpen])


  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = open;
  });

Here ref is a ref that holds the value of open from previous render and in the useEffect you can check whether that value was falsy earlier and true right now.
This functionality can also be moved to a hook
